# Why does GWT compilation require user-agent specification?

Tags: javascript, gwt, user-agent

I have used GWT for sometime now. I am now wondering what is the purpose of specifying the user-agent for the compilation process. I have tried to get some information about this but so far the only explanation I could get is that it is to create the final JS appropriate for the browser. My question is, what is different between the browsers that it requires an explicit mention of what browser we are planning to use it on? Because the end result is Javascript. Isn't JS supposed to work on all the browsers similarly as they will all implement JS? The only difference I can think of is difference in CSS for which there are browser specific css property names where required. In which case, can the output of GWT compilation not result in one single JS? What am I missing? If there is some difference in the JS, then what should be considered by those who work on JS or jQuery or Angular etc?

I have read this part of the gwt documentation,http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html -> The .cache.html Files. But I did not understand what it means exactly. What issue are they referring to?

Comment: What do you mean by "specifying the user-agent for the compilation process" and "explicit mention of what browser we are planning to use it on"?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer, I am referring to the .gwt.xml property `<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/>`

Comment: What makes you think it's required? Have you had any issue with the default values?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer, Apologies for not having put it right in the question. My intention was not to understand whether or not to specify the user.agent property rather to understand the reason for different browser specific JS/cache files generation. I mentioned about the property because they are connected.

Comment: No worries, I was trying to clarify the question; possibly debunking misconceptions and misunderstandings on your side (apparently not, which is great).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT applies browser specific optimizations. Even if javascript should be the same between browsers, especially older browsers have differences which are taken care of by GWT (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14466646/3906760 regarding the infamous XMLHTTPRequest vs. ActiveX in IE and Canvas vs. VML).

The cache files (called permutations) are specific to language and browser, so that only required code must be downloaded by a client and not one very huge file (lazy loading with GWT).

An example for replacing implementations for different browsers, see http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html (Deferred Binding Example).

Comment: Thanks @MrTux. By "optimisation" I suppose you include "adjustment" as well. From what I gather, there's quite a lot of difference between the browsers. Sharing some more here (although old) for reference if it helps anyone. [link]https://www.impressivewebs.com/7-javascript-differences-between-firefox-ie/, [link]https://dzone.com/articles/why-your-javascript-developed. I guess there are pros & cons with the browsers being this way. In any case, do libraries like jQuery/Angular JS also have this issues? and how are they to be addressed? any idea?

Comment: AngularJS and Polymer(I guess JQuery also) use polyfill(shim) for older browser. It implements features in javascript, that the browser does not support it natively, what are mostly the older browsers... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill